# Save output of awk to two different variables

Tags: bash, shell, variables, awk

Okay. I am kind of lost and google search isn't helping me much.
I have a command like:

```
filesize_filename=$(echo $line | awk ' ''{print $5":"$9}') 
echo $filesize_filename 
1024:/home/test
```

Now this one saves the two returns or awk'ed items into one variable. I'd like to achieve something like this:

```
filesize,filename=$(echo $line | awk ' ''{print $5":"$9}')
```

So I can access them individually like

```
echo $filesize
1024

echo $filename
/home/test
```

How to I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm curious - what do you think the `' '` at the start of your awk scripts does?

Comment: That's the separator / delimiter.

Comment: The default FS for awk is a space char so no need to specify it, and if you DID want to specify it then you'd use `-F' '` or `-v FS=' '`, you don't just list the char on the command line.

Answer (score 5):

Populate a shell array with the awk output and then do whatever you like with it:

```
$ fileInfo=( $(echo "foo 1024 bar /home/test" | awk '{print $2, $4}') )
$ echo "${fileInfo[0]}"
1024
$ echo "${fileInfo[1]}"
/home/test
```

If the file name can contain spaces then you'll have to adjust the FS and OFS in awk and the IFS in shell appropriately.

You may not need awk at all of course:

```
$ line="foo 1024 bar /home/test"
$ fileInfo=( $line )
$ echo "${fileInfo[1]}"
1024
$ echo "${fileInfo[3]}"
/home/test
```

but beware of globbing chars in `$line` matching on local file names in that last case. I expect there's a more robust way to populate a shell array from a shell variable but off the top of my head I can't think of it.

Answer (score 2):

Use bash's `read` for that:

```
read size name < "$(awk '{print $5, $9}' <<< "$line")"

# Now you can output them separately
echo "$size"
echo "$name"
```

Comment: Finally i used: read -a parts <<< "$line" && size="${parts[4]}" name="${parts[9]}"

Comment: Thank you all gentlemen. I cannot answer Ed though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use process substitution on awk's output:

```
read filesize filename < <(echo "$line" | awk '{print $5,$9}')
```

You can totally avoid awk by doing:

```
read _ _ _ _ filesize _ _ _ filename _ <<< "$line"
```

Comment: I was also about to add something like the latter approach to my answer, but hey!, this looks too weird!

Comment: `read -a parts <<< "$line" && size="${parts[4]}" name="${parts[9]}"` is an alternative. Does it seem less weird?

Comment: read -a parts <<< "$line" && size="${parts[4]}" name="${parts[9]}" Looks better, using awk with read does not work as awk tries to print to std output.

Comment: Of course awk prints at stdout and that's where process substitution comes into place to read the values into variables. That works with bash only.